# Uninstall a J2ME application through J2ME code?

Tags: c++, symbian, java-me, uninstallation

Is there any way to do this? I found some Symbian C++ codes that could do it but nothing in J2ME. I have a J2ME certificate and don't have Symbian C++ certificate.

Thanks in advance,
Ashish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the device manufacturer has extensions to allow this, it is not possible to uninstall JavaME midlets from JavaME code.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with Symbian C++